# redirection to https with a different port than default

Tags: node.js

Here is an example in node.js:

```
var https = require("https");
var fs = require("fs");
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("/tmp/key.pem"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("/tmp/cert.pem")
};

https.createServer(options, function(req, res) {
    res.end("secure!");
}).listen(4430);

var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function(req,res) {
    console.log(req);
    res.writeHead(301, {"location": "https://" + req.headers["host"] + req.url});
    res.end("not secure!");
}).listen(8001);
```

It will redirect http://localhost:8001 to https://localhost:8001, the problem is the https server is listening on 4430. How can I solve this?

Comment: Doesn't this work? `res.writeHead(301, {"location": "https://" + req.headers["host"] + ':4430' + req.url});`

Comment: No, that would produce an invalid url: `https://localhost:3000:4430/`

Comment: Ah right. So, how about `res.writeHead(301, {"location": "https://" + req.headers["host"].replace(":8001",":4430") + req.url});`?

Comment: Yes. That would work. A more generic solution would to splitting by ":". :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just need a little string manipulation. Instead of `req.headers["host"]`, use `req.headers["host"].split(":")[0]`.